# analyze lines in R graphs

Tags: r, linegraph

I have two different line graphs (see photo below) and I want to know the average time the line goes up and down. I produced a dummy data:

```
> dput(head(dummydata))
structure(list(cond = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Con", 
"t1"), class = "factor"), T = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), mean = c(16L, 
7L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 16L)), .Names = c("cond", "T", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: the graph]

My real data has more variability than this one though. 
Any advice on how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Are you asking for length of time that the graph goes up and down? Or are you asking about a trend line that might be derived from a decomposition of the data into  seasonality, trend, and error (https://anomaly.io/seasonal-trend-decomposition-in-r/)?

Comment: The length of time the graph goes up and down, and not the decomposition of the data. Sorry for the confusion, I corrected my use of such words in the question.

Comment: Try doing a lag comparison between means as a second variable.  Using the dplyr package, there is a lag() function that can be called using mutate().  Something like: `library(dplyr); df %>% mutate(direction = ifelse( lag(mean,1) < mean, "up", "down"))`

Comment: @RyanMorton this worked and then I used `rle` to check the patterns of the line. Thanks!